# How do I get uri from ListView item that populated by Cursor Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a ListView that populated by Cursor Adapter. Every list item has toggle button. When user switches the button I want to update corresponding row in the table for that cursor. But my Adapter can populate list with different cursors (for different uris). I find method cursor.getNotificationUri() that works as I need, except that it supports only from API level 19 whereas my app supports API level 15.

Here is event handler in MyCursorAdapter.java

```
    viewHolder.toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            int favourite = isChecked ? 1 : 0 ;
            ContentValues value = new ContentValues();
            Uri uri = cursor.getNotificationUri();
            value.put(AmdmContract.SongEntry.COLUMN_FAVORITE, favourite);
            mContext.getContentResolver()
                    .update(uri, value, where, selArgs);
        }
    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks